# Concatenation of a string with an element in an array of strings

Tags: string, string-concatenation

What's wrong with this code?

```
 String ans=strarr[f];

        for (int i=f+1; i<f+k-1; i++){
            ans=ans+(strarr[i]);
            //System.out.println(ans);
        }
        return ans;
```

ans remains as strarr[f]. Something wrong with the loop apparently because ans=ans+strarr[f+1]works perfectly fine outside the loop.

Comment: Well, it all depends on what is the value of the "k". If it's value is <=2 then the loop will never execute.

Comment: Lord I feel so inept. Stupid mistake on my part. It should've been <f+k. I'm so sorry for wasting your time.